# Handling shutdown in KMDF filter

Tags: device-driver, kmdf

I'm working on kmdf volume filter driver and wanted to handle shutdown. The article [WDM IRPs and KMDF Event Callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg583867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and comments in the WDF book seems to suggest that the WDF supports IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN only for control(non PNP) deivce. So I added call to `WdfControlDeviceInitSetShutdownNotification(WdfDeviceShutdown)` for my control object and that allowed me to save file to same volume at the time of shutdown. However the document sys that `WdfDeviceShutdown` is called before flush which I'm not seeing. I've callback for flush using EvtDeviceWdmIrpPreprocess(IRP_MJ_FLUSH). Looking at the Dbg print, I always see flush callback before `WdfDeviceShutdown` callback.

I wonder if I'm missing something. Any comments on this behavior will help me understand this better. I'm seeing flush before because control device is at volume filter level which is below file system hence executive flushes file system buffer before closing/notifying my device.

Note: If I use `WdfControlDeviceInitSetShutdownNotification(WdfDeviceLastChanceShutdown`) I get error `0xc0000189 (STATUS_TOO_LATE)` when I try to write to the file.